# onClick or onChange is not working in preline UI select component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, formik, tailwind-ui

I am using preline UI library in React for designing my site. But somehow if I use "select" with data-hs-select attribute [as per preline UI](https://preline.co/docs/advanced-select.html), onChange or onClick nothing actually works. Not even getting anything in console with onClick/onChange. But in browser interface it's showing proper selected value, and if I try useRef or document selector value I can get the proper selected value from the input.

I have tried with formik field [as='select'] but the same issue

```
 <select
      name='Country'
      data-hs-select='{
        "hasSearch": true,
        "searchPlaceholder": "Search...",
        "searchClasses": "block w-full text-sm border-gray-200 rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500 before:absolute before:inset-0 before:z-[1] dark:bg-slate-900 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600 py-2 px-3",
        "searchWrapperClasses": "bg-white p-2 -mx-1 sticky top-0 dark:bg-slate-900",
        "placeholder": "Select ...",
        "toggleTag": "<button type=\"button\"><span class=\"me-2\" data-icon></span><span class=\"text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200\" data-title></span></button>",
        "toggleClasses": "hs-select-disabled:pointer-events-none hs-select-disabled:opacity-50 relative py-3 px-4 pe-9 flex text-nowrap w-full cursor-pointer bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg text-start text-sm focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500 before:absolute before:inset-0 before:z-[1] dark:bg-slate-900 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600",
        "dropdownClasses": "mt-2 max-h-[300px] pb-1 px-1 space-y-0.5 z-20 w-full bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg overflow-hidden overflow-y-auto dark:bg-slate-900 dark:border-gray-700",
        "optionClasses": "py-2 px-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-800 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-slate-900 dark:hover:bg-slate-800 dark:text-gray-200 dark:focus:bg-slate-800",
        "optionTemplate": "<div><div class=\"flex items-center\"><div class=\"me-2\" data-icon></div><div class=\"text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200\" data-title></div></div></div>"
      }'
      className='hidden'
      onChange={() => console.log('option clicked')}
    >
      <option value=''>Choose</option>
      <option value='Australia'>Australia</option>
      <option value='Canada'>Canada</option>
      <option value='France'>France</option>
      <option value='Germany'>Germany</option>
      <option value='Italy'>Italy</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

onChange event is mentioned on preline documentation.

[Preline Docs](https://preline.co/plugins/html/advanced-select.html#js-events)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).